# Java RMI Connection Fail

Tags: java, rmi

I wrote a small rmi client server program to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit.
When I create a console client to connect to the server, it works fine.  But when I create a GUI based client that extends JApplet class, the client is not running fine.  Each time when I run the client, it is throwing an Exception with the message "***Error: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect, resolve")***.  How to solve this problem?

### Server Interface:

```
import java.rmi.*;
public interface ConvServerInterface extends Remote{
    public double celToFah(double cel)throws RemoteException;
}
```

### Server Implementation:

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
public class ConvServerMainClass extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ConvServerInterface {

public ConvServerMainClass() throws Exception{}
@Override
public double celToFah(double cel) throws RemoteException {
    return ((cel*(9.0/5.0)+32));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    ConvServerMainClass serverObj = new ConvServerMainClass();
    Naming.rebind("Conversion",serverObj);
    System.out.println("Server is ready to receiver request!");
}

}
```

### Client

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ConvClient extends JApplet implements ActionListener{

JLabel lblCel, lblFah;
JTextField txtCel, txtFah;
JButton btnConv;
JPanel pnl;

public void init()
{
    initComp();
    setActionListner();
    addComponents();
}

public void initComp()
{
    lblCel = new JLabel("Celsius: ");
    lblFah = new JLabel("Fahrenheit: ");
    txtCel = new JTextField(13);
    txtFah = new JTextField(13);
    btnConv = new JButton("Convert");
    pnl = new JPanel();
}

public void setActionListner()
{
    btnConv.addActionListener(this);
}

public void addComponents()
{
    pnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
    pnl.add(lblCel); pnl.add(txtCel);
    pnl.add(lblFah); pnl.add(txtFah);
    pnl.add(btnConv);

    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    getContentPane().add(pnl);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    double cel, fah;
    try{
        if(System.getSecurityManager() == null)
        {
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        }
        ConvServerInterface serobj =  (ConvServerInterface) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/Conversion");
        if(e.getSource()==btnConv)
        {
            cel = Double.parseDouble(txtCel.getText());
            fah = serobj.celToFah(cel);
            txtFah.setText(String.valueOf(fah));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        txtFah.setText("Error: "+ ex.getMessage());
    }

}
}
```

First, I compiled both Server side Interface and Class file.  Then, I have create a Stub Class by

```
    _rmic ConvServerMainClass_
```

Then, I start my registry by

```
   _rmiregistry_
```

Then, I run my Server Class File by

```
   _rmiregistry_
```

Finally, I copied both Server Interface Class file and Stub Class file to the Client Side and I compile and run my client by

```
   _javac ConvClient.java_  
   _appletviewer ConvClient.java_
```

Comment: Did you remember to create the Registry?

Comment: Yes.  I have start my Registry by rmiregistry command

Comment: Can you please do `ex.printStackTrace()` when the exception is catched?

Comment: You may need to see item A.1 of the RMI FAQ. According to your post, you are running the Registry twice, and never running your sever at all. Please correct. Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.